# What's the history behind the first btc exchange

Tags: exchanges, buy-bitcoins, history, market

I've found out that the first BTC exchange was "BitcoinMarket.com" but I didn't find any information on it or any other exchanges that started at that time.

So the question is how did this first market came to be? How did it start? Why was it closed? Who started it and why?

I would be really grateful for any more info on this.